# Why is it we can't print out array variable content in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, variables

I'm used to javascript where if for exemple I call :

```
var tab1 = [0,1,2,3,4];
```

I can call tab1, and it returns my array content as :

```
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

I've noticed in java if I declare an integer array like so :

```
 int tab1[] = {0,1,2,3};
```

If I want to print out my array the only way I tought of was doing a loop to print out

```
tab1[i];
```

If I call "tab1" alone, I get something like : "[I@15db9742", but why ? What is that piece of code, and why can't we just call variables as loosely ?

Comment: Use `Arrays.toString`.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array but the other Q&A has a better explanation of why `[I@15db9742` happens.

Comment: I@15db9742 is a memory adress. I can't explain the Why? I can only say because Java.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4

Comment: I guess Reimeus beat me to the punch and I didn't notice. I had tried to close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29140402/2891664 which has the better explanation I was referring to.